# 'pip install nlg' keeps erroring out with the same error on multiple environments/platforms

Tags: python-3.x, pip, spacy, nlg, gramex

can anyone successfully "pip install nlg"?

i get the below picture when i do. also below are some excerpts from the error message.

```
   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
```

```
      × Encountered error while trying to install package.
      ╰─> preshed
```

i have tried from from windows 10 pc and my macbook. the picture above is from github codespace their default image.

expecting pip to successfully install the package nlg and not error out on the 'building dependencies...' stage

```
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
    Running setup.py clean for blis
  Failed to build preshed thinc blis
  Installing collected packages: wasabi, plac, cymem, wheel, tqdm, srsly, setuptools, preshed, numpy, murmurhash, Cython, blis, thinc
    Running setup.py install for preshed: started
    Running setup.py install for preshed: finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
    × Running setup.py install for preshed did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [10 lines of output]
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        running build_ext
        building 'preshed.maps' extension
        gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/python/3.10.4/include/python3.10 -I/usr/local/python/3.10.4/include/python3.10 -c preshed/maps.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/preshed/maps.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
        gcc: error: preshed/maps.cpp: No such file or directory
        gcc: fatal error: no input files
        compilation terminated.
        error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
        [end of output]
  
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: legacy-install-failure
  
  × Encountered error while trying to install package.
  ╰─> preshed
  
  note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
  hint: See above for output from the failure.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: You will have an easier time using a version of python that was supported/tested at the time of the release, which looks like python 3.7 at the latest.

Comment: thank you @aab switching to python 3.7.4 did the trick....how did you see that it was python 3.7? the latest version of nlg was Released: Jul 23, 2022 per https://pypi.org/project/nlg/0.1.3/ and 3.10 was released 4 October 2021 per https://www.python.org/doc/versions/

Comment: The requirements for `nlg` include `spacy==2.1.8` (checked here https://github.com/gramener/gramex-nlg/blob/dev/setup.py by following the "Homepage" link from https://pypi.org/project/nlg/), and https://pypi.org/project/spacy/2.1.8 shows python 3.7 as the most recent supported version in the package classifiers at the bottom left. The difference is that python 3.7 can often install precompiled wheels while newer versions of python have to build from the sdist, and sometimes older sdists can be buggy or no longer work with the newest versions of pip or setuptools.

Answer (score 0):

switching to python 3.7.4 from 3.10 did the trick

thanks @aab